# fread hangs — PHP

Tags: sockets

I created a socket using fsockopen($host,$port), sent data using fwrite, and tried to read data using fread. It seems like fsockopen successfully created the socket, fwrite successfully sent data to the socket (returns positive number — 4), but fread hangs. It looks like it is waiting for data to read, but I don't understand why.. fwrite was successful. I tried using socket_create, socket_connect, socket_send, and socket_recv instead fwrite and fread, but the same thing happens.

Below is an abstract of my code:

```
$socket = fsockopen($host,$port,$errno,$errstr);
if(!$socket){
     echo "$errstr ($errno)<br>";
}

...
$example; //string to send
fwrite($socket,pack("N",strlen($example)),4);
$result = fread($socket,4); <-- Hangs and eventually shuts down the server.
...
```

I have few successful send/read codes before that fread..

```
$status = stream_get_meta_data($socket);
var_dump($status);
```

This outputs the following array:

```
array(7) { 
["stream_type"]=> string(14) "tcp_socket/ssl" 
["mode"]=> string(2) "r+" 
["unread_bytes"]=> int(0) 
["seekable"]=> bool(false) 
["timed_out"]=> bool(false) 
["blocked"]=> bool(true) 
["eof"]=> bool(false) }
```

It's been bothering me for a long time. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using stream functions for socket communication you probably want to use [`fflush()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fflush.php) to ensure you actually send data on the wire, otherwise this short of an item might just be sitting in the stream output buffer.

This should not be an issue with [`socket_send()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-send.php) though. Since you are saying the result is the same, I'd suggest re-checking what sort of *application protocol* you are working with - the other side might be expecting more then 4 bytes to generate a response.

The last resort is always a packet sniffer like [`tcpdump(1)`](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html) or [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. I finally solved my problem and it was due to my stupid mistake... I had to send another data to the socket but I didn't. Your answer still helped me to try different things and I learned new things such as fflush, tcpdump, and wireshark. Thank you again!!

Comment: That's pretty much what I said in the second part of my answer. You can also accept answers, you know ... :)

Comment: Sorry I didn't know how to accept your answer. I just figured it out! Thanks a lot for your help! :)